# laravel-echo-server not listening all notification

Tags: laravel, laravel-echo, laravel-broadcast

I want to make real time notification in my app. I am using Laravel Broadcast Notification, Laravel Echo and Laravel Echo Server.in my app in local notification listen for all user but in server if notification added for 5 users then listen for 2 to 3 users and else users log save in laravel.log file.

**CODE**

// controller file

```
$users = User::whereHas('dealerRoles', function ($query) {
                $query->where('name', DealerRole::DEALERSHIP_DIRECTOR);
                $query->orWhere('name', DealerRole::DEALERSHIP_PRINCIPAL);
                $query->orWhere('name', DealerRole::DEALERSHIP_MANAGER);
            })->whereHas('dealerships', function ($query) use ($listing) {
                $query->where('dealerships.id', $listing->owner_id);
            })->get();

            \Notification::send($users, (new ListingApproved($listing)));
```

// notification file(ListingApproved.php)

```
class ListingApproved extends Notification implements ShouldQueue{
use Queueable;

private $listing;

/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Listing $listing)
{
    $this->listing = $listing;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database', 'broadcast'];
}

public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'listing_id' => $this->listing->id,
        'message' => 'Your Listing has been approved Successfully.'
    ];
}
```

}

// laravel-echo-server.json

```
{
"authHost": ["http://dealers.cc/", "http://admin.videocarsales.cc/"],
"authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
"clients": [
    {
        "appId": "31071dab508dc1bb",
        "key": "8262eb7c6589432f457ad25b83d4cb5a"
    }
],
"database": "redis",
"databaseConfig": {
    "redis": {},
    "sqlite": {
        "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
    }
},
"devMode": true,
"host": null,
"port": "7878",
"protocol": "http",
"socketio": {},
"sslCertPath": "",
"sslKeyPath": "",
"sslCertChainPath": "",
"sslPassphrase": "",
"apiOriginAllow": {
    "allowCors": true,
    "allowOrigin": "http://localhost:80",
    "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
    "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
}
```

}

// front end for listen notification

```
Echo.private('App.Domain.User.User.' + '{{ auth()->user()->id }}')
            .notification((notification) => {
                console.log('yes');
                Messenger().post({
                    message: 'Your Listing las been approved Successfully.',
                    type: 'success',
                    showCloseButton: true
                });
            });
```

//laravel.log

```
[2018-06-13 08:13:09] production.INFO: Broadcasting [Illuminate\Notifications\Events\BroadcastNotificationCreated] on channels [private-App.Domain.User.User.49] with payload:
{
"listing_id": 1,
"message": "Your Listing has been approved Successfully.",
"id": "acb1f428-0116-43a4-88cd-53e35089084a",
"type": "App\\Notifications\\ListingApproved",
"socket": null}
```

please help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It happened to me, check your 
BROADCAST_DRIVER=
I think that if you are seeing it in LOG its not defined in your .env file

    __| Supported: "pusher", "redis", "log", "null"__

Which driver are you using?